# LaravelFacebookSDK Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api

How I can increment the timeout from the laravelfacebooksdk, i get the error:

[Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException]
Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

Note that i use the wrapper laravel facebook sdk

Answer (score 0):

I modified this files to allow a new http_client_handler
I create a new instance and in this updated the htt_client_handler, updated the composer.json for read the Facebooksdk classes.

composer.json

```
"autoload": {"classmap":
["database","/var/www/laravel/vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook"]
```

class xxx.php

```
class LongerTimeoutHttpClient extends 
Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookStreamHttpClient
{public function send($url, $method, $body, array $headers, $timeOut){
$timeOut *= 4;
return parent::send($url, $method, $body, $headers, $timeOut);}}

public function handle(SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdk $fb)
{ 
$fbStream = new Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookStream;
$fb2 = $fb->newInstance([
'app_id' => env('FACEBOOK_APP_ID'),
'app_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'),
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
'http_client_handler' => new LongerTimeoutHttpClient($fbStream),]);
}
```

In this way i allow the value timeout in the instances $fb.